# perl one liner to add column to file if second field matches

Tags: perl

I have a file that for some rows has 4 fields and for some rows has 3 fields, and looks like:

```
1 rs17125090 63988904 ENSG00000142856
7 7.87455705 ENSG00000075303
```

In the cases where the row has 3 fields, the second field matches "number.longer number" whereas if the row has 4 fields, the second field matches "rsnumber". In the instances where the row has 3 fields, I would like to add a field in the third column that contains a number equal to the second field, split by ".". For example, the resulting file would look like:

```
1 rs17125090 63988904 ENSG00000142856
7 7.87455705 87455705 ENSG00000075303
```

My perl one liner is:

```
perl -e 'for(`cat file`){my@L=split;if($L[1]=~m/^\d+\.\d+$/){my@snp=split(/\./,$L[1]);splice(@L,2,0,$snp[1])}}open OUT,">file.new";print OUT "@L\n"; close OUT'
```

But I just get an empty file. Can someone fix this/let me know what's going wrong?

Comment: It would be useful for you to show a readable version of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be very careful when writing one-line programs. Many of the normal safeguards are not in place, and it is far less easy to spot an error when ther is no layout

Your code is equivalent to this program

```
for ( `cat file` ) {

    my @L = split;

    if ( $L[1] =~ m/^\d+\.\d+$/ ) {
        my @snp = split( /\./, $L[1] );
        splice( @L, 2, 0, $snp[1] );
    }
}

open OUT, ">file.new";
print OUT "@L\n";
close OUT;
```

Can you see now where the problem lies?

This should do what you need

```
perl -anE 'splice @F, 2, 0, $F[1] =~ /\.(\d+)/; say "@F";' myfile
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments on my (now deleted) answer. I said _"The for loop body only runs once"_ which you corrected: _"The loop body runs once for each line in the output of cat file."_ (I didn't know that backticks behaved that way in list context.) I also posted a mangled version of my fix due to a copy-and-paste mix-up. It should have said: [perl -pe "s/\.(\d+)/.$1 $1/" <file >file.new]

Comment: @Buster: Also note that you should use `$1` and not `\1` in the replacement string of a Perl substitution. That solution might be okay, but we don't know that there are never any other dot characters elsewhere in the lines, which would cause it to fail.

Comment: "Fixed" in my comment above refers to using $1 and not \1, not to the second criticism, which you added afterwards, and which is also true.